# Where is Cuda class in java opencv 3.1?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to implement java code that was written with OpenCV 2.4.1 that required the import of

> org.opencv.gpu.DeviceInfo

which doesn't seem to exist in the 3.1 version in Java. It does exist in the 3.1 C++ docs under the same name of DeviceInfo but in the class Cuda instead of GPU. Is it renamed somewhere in Java or was it eliminated in the 3.1 Java version?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for OpenCV in Java as well and found better use of not OpenCV default Java bindings, but C++ to Java javacpp-presets. They are using generic approach to convert CPP API to Java, you need to understand little bit C++ way of thinking, as in the end you will use C++ style development wrapped in Java. They are quite good in what they are doing, their libs are not limited to OpenCv and are quite performant, in case of OpenCV:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>${moduleName}-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${moduleVersion}-1.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

Details available here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets